# How does the covariant derivative satisfy the Leibniz rule?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, differentiation, curvature

In Carroll's "Spacetime and Geometry", he states on page 95 (section 3.2) that the covariant derivative, $\nabla$, is a map from $\left(k, l\right)$ tensor fields to $\left(k, l+1\right)$ tensor fields which satisfies various properties, one of which is the following Leibniz rule: $$\nabla \left(T \otimes S\right) = \left(\nabla T\right) \otimes S + T \otimes \left( \nabla S\right)\text{.}\tag{p.95}$$ If we express this in terms of the tensors' components, it seems to me that we should have $$\nabla \left(T \otimes S\right)_{\mu}^{\ \ \nu \rho} = \nabla\left(T\right)_{\mu}^{\ \ \nu} S^{\rho} + T_{\mu}\nabla\left(S\right)^{\nu \rho}\text{.}\tag{2}$$

However based on the definition given for $\nabla$ on page 97 in terms of the connection coefficients, it seems that, for vectors $T$ and $S$, we should have $$\nabla \left(T \otimes S\right)_{\mu}^{\ \ \nu \rho} = \partial_{\mu}\left(T^{\nu}S^{\rho}\right) + \Gamma_{\mu \lambda}^{\nu}T^{\lambda}S^{\rho} + \Gamma_{\mu \lambda}^{\rho}T^{\nu}S^{\lambda} = \nabla\left(T\right)_{\mu}^{\ \ \nu} S^{\rho} + T^{\nu}\nabla\left(S\right)_{\mu}^{\ \ \rho}\text{.}\tag{3}$$

Therefore, the definition given doesn't seem to have the required Leibniz rule property. Could someone please point out where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that $T$ and $S$ are supposed to be $(1,0)$ tensor fields we can see that
Eq. (2) is wrong immediately, because the expression $ \nabla (S)^{ \nu \rho} $ has the wrong indices (it should have 1 co- and 1 contra-variant by definition of $S$ and $\nabla$).

If we write the covariant derivative in abstract index notation, then the Leibniz rule can be stated as
$$\nabla_a (T^bS^c) = ( \nabla_a T^b )S^c + T^b ( \nabla_a S^c),$$
which gives us the correct formula (Eq. 3) immediatly.

The expression
$$\nabla \left(T \otimes S\right) = \left(\nabla T\right) \otimes S + T \otimes \left( \nabla S\right) \tag{1 } $$
has a subtle problem and should be avoided.

To explain the problem:

$\nabla \left(T \otimes S\right)$ is a section of $T^* (M) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(M) $, where $T(M)$ is the tangent bundle of the base manifold $M$ and $T^* (M)$ the cotangent bundle of $M$. The $T$ in $T(M)$ and $T^*(M)$ has nothing to do with the tensor $T$, bad notation here sorry.

The expression $\left(\nabla T\right) \otimes S $  is also a section of $T^* (M) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(M)$ (after expanding using associativity).

But the expression $T \otimes \left( \nabla S\right)$ is not a section of $T^* (M) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(M)$, but rather a section of $T(M) \otimes T^* (M) \otimes T (M)$.

But this means that we can not do the addition: $\left(\nabla T\right) \otimes S + T \otimes \left( \nabla S\right)$, since the two expression are not of the same tensor field type.

Therefore it must be understood that we first change the type of $T \otimes \left( \nabla S\right)$ (via permutation of the first and second factor) to a section of $T^* (M) \otimes T(M) \otimes T(M)$ and then add them.

To illustrate this consider your example:
Let $C$ be the type changed version of $T \otimes \left( \nabla S\right)$. Then we have $C_{\mu}{}^{\nu \rho} = (T \otimes ( \nabla S) )^{\nu}{}_{\mu}{}^{\rho}$.
And therefore from formula 1
$$(\nabla T \otimes S)_\mu {}^{\nu \rho}  = (\nabla T)_\mu{}^\nu  S^\rho +C_{\mu}{}^{\nu \rho} = (\nabla T)_\mu{}^\nu  S^\rho +T^\nu (\nabla S)_{\mu}{}^\rho$$
which is the same as your equation 3.

This type changing procedure is explicitly done when writing the Leibniz formula in the abstract index notation as above (this is why $a,b$ are inverted in the second summand).

**Edit**:

As pointed out in the comments by @jawheele we can also formulate the Leibniz rule without ambiguity in the usual notation as follows:

Denote by $\Gamma(-)$ spaces of smooth sections.

If $E$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$, then we can view a smooth section $s \in \Gamma(T^*(M) \otimes E )$ as a $C^\infty$-linear map $\tilde{s}: \Gamma( T(M)) \to  \Gamma( E)$ that is defined by letting $\tilde{s} (X)$ be the contraction of the first and second slot of $X \otimes s$ for every vector field $X \in \Gamma (T(M))$.

Therefore we can view the  covariant derivative applied to an arbitrary (smooth) tensor field $F$ on $M$ as a linear map.

We denote the resulting linear map applied to a vector field $X \in \Gamma ( T(M))$ by $\nabla_X F$. So to be explicit: $\nabla_X F$ is obtained by contracting the first and second slot in $X \otimes (\nabla F)$.

Then the Leibniz rule can be restated as:

$$ \nabla_X( T \otimes S) = (\nabla_X T) \otimes S + T \otimes (\nabla_X S)$$
for every vector field $X \in \Gamma( T(M))$.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by observing that the index-free notation is perfectly capable of expressing this property in an unambiguous way by writing
$$\nabla_X(T \otimes S) = (\nabla_X T) \otimes S + T \otimes (\nabla_X S).$$
As it is, the answer reads as insinuating that abstract index notation is inherently less ambiguous, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: @jawheele I never suggested that the index free notation can not express the Leibniz property. I only wrote that the "type changing" map has to be built into the expression. So if $C$ is the type changing map the Leibniz rule could also be stated as $\nabla (T \otimes S) = ( \nabla T) \otimes S + C ( T \otimes (\nabla S))$. All i want to suggest is, that the abstract index notation is very usefull to express such type changes (and also for contractions, factor permutations, symmetrization and metric type changing).

Answer (score 7):

Carroll on p. 95 means that
$$\nabla_X \left(T \otimes S\right) ~=~ \left(\nabla_X T\right) \otimes S + T \otimes \left(\nabla_X S\right),\qquad X\in\Gamma(TM),$$
and hence
$$\nabla_{\mu} \left(T \otimes S\right) ~=~ \left(\nabla_{\mu} T\right) \otimes S + T \otimes \left(\nabla_{\mu} S\right).$$
So OP's eq. (3) is right, while OP's eq. (2) is wrong.